# Using BCryptAddContextFunction and BCryptRemoveContextFunction to prioritize Schannel Cipher Suites for TLS 1.2

Tags: c, winapi, encryption, bcrypt, tls1.2

I have a list of cipher suits which should be acceptable on my server.
For example: I would like to handling only those suites in system

"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

I tried to use samples from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930(v=vs.85).aspx#adding__removing__and_prioritizing_cipher_suites
but... this works only theoretically

```
// for visual c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Bcrypt.lib")
#ifndef NT_SUCCESS
#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) ((NTSTATUS)(Status) >= 0)
#endif

void addToTop(LPWSTR wszCipher){

    SECURITY_STATUS Status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    wprintf_s(wszCipher);
    printf_s("\r\n");
    Status = BCryptAddContextFunction(
        CRYPT_LOCAL,
        L"SSL",
        NCRYPT_SCHANNEL_INTERFACE,
        wszCipher,
        CRYPT_PRIORITY_TOP);
    if (FAILED(Status))
    {
        printf_s("\n**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptAddContextFunction\n", Status);
    }

}

void printCipherSuites()
{
    HRESULT Status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    DWORD   cbBuffer = 0;
    PCRYPT_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONS pBuffer = NULL;

    Status = BCryptEnumContextFunctions(
        CRYPT_LOCAL,
        L"SSL",
        NCRYPT_SCHANNEL_INTERFACE,
        &cbBuffer,
        &pBuffer);
    if (FAILED(Status))
    {
        printf_s("\n**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptEnumContextFunctions\n", Status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if (pBuffer == NULL)
    {
        printf_s("\n**** Error pBuffer returned from BCryptEnumContextFunctions is null");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    for (UINT index = 0; index < pBuffer->cFunctions; ++index)
    {
        printf_s("\n%S", pBuffer->rgpszFunctions[index]);
    }
Cleanup:
    if (pBuffer != NULL)
    {
        BCryptFreeBuffer(pBuffer);
    }
    getchar();
}

int removeSth()
{
    printf_s("\nRemoving TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
    LPWSTR wszCipher = L"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
    SECURITY_STATUS Status = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    Status = BCryptRemoveContextFunction(
        CRYPT_LOCAL,
        L"SSL",
        NCRYPT_SCHANNEL_INTERFACE,
        wszCipher);
    if (FAILED(Status))
    {
        printf_s("\n**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptRemoveContextFunction\n", Status);
    }
    return 0;
}
void main()
{
    addToTop(L"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256");
    addToTop(L"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
    addToTop(L"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
    printCipherSuites();
}
```

You can see - calling BCryptAddContextFunction does not change anything in system. I do not have failed Status for this call, however - when I list all cipher suites - there is no TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, LS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 on the list

I cannot find a working WinAPI sample. What should I change in my code to prioritize Schannel Cipher Suites?

edit:
I discovered an interesting thing... WinApi remove/add functions returns STATUS_SUCCESS - but SSL Cipher Suites list is not updated.

We also cannot see the results of BCryptAddContextFunction/BCryptRemoveContextFunction in
gpedit.msc, Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Local Group Policy Editor -> SSL Cipher Suite Order